# Same subnet, 3 different VLANs - How?

Tags: cisco, bridging

A customer has a network: 10.0.0.0/24.
The gateway 10.0.0.1/24 is represented by an SVI for VLAN 10 on a core switch.
Downstream there is an ACE Load balancer, which has a BVI.
This BVI's IP address is 10.0.0.4/24 and bridges two VLAN's 20 and 30.

New applications are all build in the same /24.  The VIP IP allocate for these new apps also is assigned from the same /24.  As an example:

```
!-- Example application
!-- Frontend VIP IP
10.0.0.7

!-- Backend Servers
10.0.0.8
10.0.0.9
```

In ARP in the Core, the SVI is (obviously) part of VLAN 10, however, the same IP is shown belonging to VLAN 20 down in the ACE per ARP.  VIP IP's show up in VLAN 20, backend servers show up in VLAN 30.  All the same /24.

```
!-- SVI in the core
Interface Vlan10
  ip address 10.0.0.2/24
  hsrp version 2
  hsrp 10
    preempt
    ip 10.0.0.1
  no shut

!-- Sh ip arp output (simulated)
10.0.0.1    -    0000.0cxx.xxxx    vlan10
10.0.0.2    -    xxxx.xxxx.xxxx    vlan10


!-- Int/BVI config in the ACE
 interface vlan 20
  bridge-group 20
  no normalization
  mac-sticky enable
  no icmp-guard
  service-policy input VIP-policy
  no shut

Interface vlan 30
  bridge-group 20
  no normalization
  mac-sticky enable
  no icmp-guard
  service-policy input backend-server-policy
  no shut

Interface bvi 20
  ip address 10.0.0.5 255.255.255.0
  alias 10.0.0.4 255.255.255.0
  peer ip address 10.0.0.6 255.255.255.0
  no shut

!-- Sh arp output (simulated)

10.0.0.1    0000.0cxx.xxxx    vlan20
10.0.0.4    xxxx.xxxx.xxxx    bvi20
10.0.0.7    xxxx.xxxx.xxxx    vlan20
10.0.0.8    xxxx.xxxx.xxxx    vlan30
10.0.0.9    xxxx.xxxx.xxxx    vlan30
```

How does this work (It does by the way)?  Specifically from a tagging perspective, how is it possible for the traffic to move from the endpoint through the LB and the core successfully?  Again, the only bridging is internal to the LB, not between the LB and anything else.

Comment: Unless you are configuring VLAN trunks, VLAN tags are meaningless.  If two VLANs are bridged, then for all intents and purposes, they are the same VLAN.

Comment: How are they meaningless?  A host on SW1, on a port tagged for VLAN30, isn't going to be able to see it's gateway (and SVI for VLAN 10 on SW2) - even if there is no trunk link connecting the two switches... ARP's are going to stay in VLAN30, and no routing will be possible if the gateway can't be found (no ARP).  What am I missing Ron?  No indignation here just general curiosity.  Thank you in advance for your reply !

Comment: The port is not tagged unless it's a trunk port. If you bridge vlans, you make them the same vlan.  ARP and other bcast will be forwarded on both vlans. By definition that makes them the same vlan.

Comment: That part I get / understand.  My problem is that there is no bridging between the ACE and the upstream switch.. The bridging aspect of the above config is completely local to the ACE - for example BVI20 / VLAN20, is still VLAN20 to the core switch where the SVI sits, which represents VLAN10.  The ACE is a linecard in a 6500, there is definitely a trunk between the ACE/6500 and the core switch containing all 3 VLAN's.  Thanks in advance for your help and continued feedback Ron!

Comment: Then perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Can you post a diagram?

Comment: Absolutely, I'll work on something, may take a day to get something together.

Comment: What is the link between SW1 and the ACE configured as? I'd say it is an access port. The reason being that if it is an access port, as Ron mentioned above there won't be any tagging of the packets. Therefore on SW1 everything will appear as though it's in VLAN10 because it is the ACE combining (bridging) the VLANs together. In other words, SW1 will see the traffic on VLAN10 even though the ACE may be sending it on VLAN20 and SW1 has a VLAN20 as well. (I hope that makes sense but I fear it doesn't.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @AL, to really provide an answer, we would need to see the output of a command like `show run | i svclc|module|vlan-group` which should give any relevant information on how traffic is routed through the line cards.

Comment: Hey all - my profound apologies on this thread as it was a really interesting one, however, I no longer have this client (haven't for a while) so it'd be hard for me to replicate their setup precisely.  I have a colleague who works with them so I can see if I can get some sanitized configs or topologies I can generalize to bring this topic to a clean conclusion for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is that switches don't care about VLANs *in other switches*.  The boundaries created by a VLAN only apply *on that switch*.

In this case it sounds like an access port on VLAN 10 in the core switch is plugged into an access port in either VLAN 20 or 30 in the switch with the ACE.  Since they're access ports there's no tagging and while I would consider that a misconfiguration and "wrong" it will work just fine as a way to bridge VLAN 10 and the other VLAN.  Since VLANs 20 and 30 are bridged explicitly by the ACE that makes all three VLANs into one broadcast domain.

You might think of the VLANs as ethernet hubs. Each VLAN is a hub, a broadcast domain. The bridge statement in the ACE connects the 20 and 30 "hub" and turns them into one domain so they can see each other. There is obviously something connecting 10 into the one of the others as well but there isn't enough info to know what.  Probably it's an access port with each end in a different VLAN or it's a trunk port with "mismatched" default VLAN.

*Bonus info because hubs aren't common anymore:*
In the olden days people used hubs for ethernet connections (when they weren't hiding from dinosaurs). Computers were plugged into hubs and each hub was a broadcast domain (and a collision domain but we're not going there).  VLANs didn't exist so each hub was it's own domain and computers plugged into hub 20 couldn't see other computers that were plugged into hub 30 unless the two hubs were connected by running a cable between them (a crossover cable because MDIX didn't exist yet).

Comment: I was going to wait for OzNerd to post the answer as well but honestly you posted the same solution in the form of an actual answer so I'll accept this.  I get what you're saying but in this case I believe it was a trunk link upstream and that all of the VLAN's were tagged.  Regardless - if anyone were to have this similar problem, your solution is going to be the likely correct answer.  Thanks Dave / Oz !!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, my best guess is that you have some configurations similar to **Private Vlan**. So here primary vlan will be Vlan10 and both Vlan20 & Vlan30 will be the secondary vlans for Vlan10.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

IP connectivity between devices on all three VLANs works because they are bridged together by a networking device, the ACE load balancer. Neither the BVI or SVI have anything to do with it. The SVI is presumably the default gateway out of the Ethernet segment(s).

Comment: Not the case - only VLAN20/30 are bridged, VLAN 10 is not and is completely localized within the upstream switch.  See my last posted comment on the main question for context.  Regardless thanks for taking a stab at this.